# mongo query with aggregation method

Tags: mongodb

my  user schema like this.....

```
 username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true
    },
    country_code: {
        type: String,
        default: 'US'
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    created_by: {
        type: String 
    },
    last_updated_by: {
        type: String 
    },
```

now i want to aggregate the value and get, in that how many users created  in that date and 
         count it..
         please help me

```
    example:
    output:
    dates:["12-11-2019","13-11-2019","14-11-2019"]
    counts:[4,5,6]
```

Comment: i think you need [$group with $sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)

Comment: i need like this     output:
    dates:["12-11-2019","13-11-2019","14-11-2019"]
    counts:[4,5,6]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's say you need to count registered user group them by `created_at` field. The simplest trick i can think of for your case is to use `$group` stage twice. First, you `$sum` registered user of each days like so:

```
{
  $group: {
      _id: {createdAt: '$created_at'},
      count: {$sum: 1}
  }
},
```

and then, you call `$group` stage again and use `$push` operator this time and set `_id` to null

```
{
  $group: {
      _id: null,
      dates: {
          $push: '$_id.createdAt'
      },
      counts: {
          $push: '$count'
      }
  }
}
```